# Spring Config Server - How to i access files inside folders per environment?

Tags: spring, gitlab, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a folder like this in my gitlab

```
test-project/
     DEV/application-testconfig.properties
     SYS/application-testconfig.properties
     PROD/application-testconfig.properties
     appication-commonconfig.properties
```

These testconfig.properties file contents differ per environment

How do i access the files based on the environment in my spring config server?

Ex:
I would like to use the url like the below for prod, dev:

https://my.configserver.com/my-project/prod/testconfig/master,

https://my.configserver.com/my-project/dev/testconfig/master

also I should be able to access appication-commonconfig.properties

The problem is i am migrating around 30 config files per each environment. the filename in one environment is similar in the other. I can't rename all the files to have "-dev" or "-prod" in it

I've tried with different paths but no luck

Comment: why not give them different names? like for example `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` would automatically look for `application-dev.properties`

Comment: Hi @JAsgarov, the problem is i have 20 to 30 configuration files per environment.
all the environment has the same file name but with different content in it